# How to show loader at soon as page is loaded

Tags: jquery

we all have used gmail or hotmail. When ever we enter it first shows a loader then as soon as page is ready the loader is hidden. How is it achievable?

I know that through jquery as soon as page is ready I can hide the loader like this.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#loader").toggle();
});

<div id="loader"></div>
<style>
.loader {
border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
border-radius: 50%;
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
</style>

<div>Main Content website</div>
```

This div is above all the `div` in the body. 
But how do I show loading div before the page is ready?

Comment: Put it in the HTML and style it with CSS

Comment: css style selector doesn't match the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via JavaScript. Look at how w3schools have done it pretty simple. Easy peasy lemon squeezy

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_loader5

Answer (score 0):

If you need the whole page loaded(including images, text...) you should use `$(window).load` instead of `$(document).ready` since `$(document).ready` is fired as soon the DOM is loaded.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#loader").toggle();
    $("#mainContent").show(); // Page content
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Andrés beat me to it, but here is another example:

```
$("#main-content").hide();
     $(window).load(function () {
        $("#loader").fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $("#main-content").fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Initially set the `loader` to display in your HTML/CSS, so that you can see it as soon as the page is visited, and then you can use `$(window).load` to hide it when the page is completely loaded.

Additionally, you can use `window.onbeforeunload` to show it again when user navigates to another page on your site or navigates out of your site.